# Reading blob from DuckDB with C++ API

Tags: c++, duckdb

Using the C++ API to DuckDB I can create a blob from

```cpp
std::vector<char> binary_data;
// write data to vector here
auto value = duckdb::Value::BLOB((duckdb::const_data_ptr_t)binary_data.data(), binary_data.size());
```

and write it to a DuckDB table.

Using the C API I can read such a blob successfully using:

```c
duckdb_blob blob = duckdb_value_blob(&result, col, row);
```

and from this fill the vector using `blob.data` and `blob.size`
but I cannot see how to retrieve the data and size from a `duckdb::Value::BLOB` with the C++ API.
Can anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with

```
  const std::string blob = value.GetValueUnsafe<std::string>();
```

Then proceed with the C++ string as desired

Comment: This works, thanks. So does `std::string blob = duckdb::StringValue::Get(value);`. The C++ string indeed contains the binary data including nulls and the length is correct